# How to use Login Response values in profileVC without using segue in swift

Tags: json, swift, model

I need to use login response values in profile viewcontroller, for that i have created model for login response like below

```
struct LoginModel: Codable {
let result:Result1?
let error:ErrorStatus?
}

struct ErrorStatus:Codable {
let message:String?
let meaning:String?
}
// MARK: - Result
struct Result1: Codable {
let userdata: Userdata
let token: String
}

// MARK: - Userdata
struct Userdata: Codable {
let id: Int
let fname, lname, email: String
let emailVcode, nickName: JSONNull?
let userType, isFeatured, emailVerifiedAt, password: String
let phoneCountryCode: JSONNull?
let phoneNo: String
}
```

I have added to LoginModel in LoginViewController likebelow

```
do{

let jsonModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginModel.self, from: data)
print("new model \(jsonModel.result)")
         
DispatchQueue.main.sync{
    if jsonModel.error != nil{
}
else{
    var nameLogin = jsonModel.result?.userdata.fname
    var emailLogin = jsonModel.result?.userdata.email
    print("login name \(String(describing: nameLogin))")
    
    let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as? HomeViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    
}
}
}
```

Now i need total LoginModel values(fname,lname,email.. and all values) in ProfileViewcontroller, how to do that, Please help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send data directly from your LoginVC to your profileVC:

```
    do{
        
        let jsonModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginModel.self, from: data)
        print("new model \(jsonModel.result)")
        
        DispatchQueue.main.sync{
            if jsonModel.error != nil{
            }
            else{
                var nameLogin = jsonModel.result?.userdata.fname
                var emailLogin = jsonModel.result?.userdata.email
                print("login name \(String(describing: nameLogin))")
                let storyboard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
                let homeVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as? HomeViewController
                let profileVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "yourProfileVCIdentifier") as? ProfileViewController
                profileVC?.userData = jsonModel.result?.userdata
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeVc!, animated: true)
                
            }
        }
    }
```

then of course you need a variable to hold data in your ProfileViewController

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var userData:Userdata?

    //other stuff
}
```

however if you keep using your UserData as you should, I think you can consider to save those data in plist or `UserDefaults`

Comment: `Cannot assign value of type 'Userdata.Type' to type 'Userdata'` error

Comment: see update, in your case should be `jsonModel.result?.userdata`

Comment: where should i write this code, bcz i am not using any navigation..  i try to write in loginVC viewdidload.. getting error

Comment: `Instance member 'result' cannot be used on type 'LoginModel'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?`. error if i write in loginVC viewdidload

Comment: in your login function inside loginVC.... see updated answer.

Comment: pls answer here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66438701/how-to-create-and-handle-parameters-and-success-response-of-json-in-one-functio/66439030#66439030

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create like this:

```swift
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    private var profile: LoginModel?
    
    static func create(with profile: LoginModel?) -> HomeViewController? {
        let controller = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as? HomeViewController
        controller?.profile = profile
        return controller
    }
}
```

or just declare an internal property:

```swift
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    var profile: LoginModel?
}
```

```swift
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as? HomeViewController
vc.profile = jsonModel
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

Comment: not in `HomeViewController` i need login values in profileVC.. pls guide

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it is different? Instead of creating `HomeViewController`, you create `ProfileViewController`.

Comment: i dont use `pushViewController` from loginVC to profileVC to send like this `vc.profile = jsonModel`.. thats the issue

Comment: So how can you push to `ProfileViewController`? Do you use segue?

Comment: i am going `loginVC-> HomeVC -> profileVC` like this no connection b/w login to profile

Comment: oh got it, so you should send the data throw home controller then profile controller :)

Comment: how?, would you post answer for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229238/discussion-between-iosswift-and-son).

Answer (score 1):

Many solutions for this

1. Define a variable in HomeViewController and you can pass data like:

   let homeVC = HomeViewController(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: nil)
   homeVC.data = userData
2. Use delegate
3. Use UserDefaults

In LoginController:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(userData, forKey: "user")
```

In HomeViewController:

```
let data = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "user")
```