# How to create, and handle parameters and success response of JSON in one function to call that function in all Viewcontrollers in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, function

In my project i have all POST method JSON URL's, so i need to create one separate function where i need to pass `url and parameters` and i need to handle response as well .. Now I want to use that function in all viewcontrollers with differnt urls and parameters... but i am unable to create separate function for JSON

I am writing same code for all viewcontrollrs with different `url`s and `jsonpostParameters` like below

```
  func loginService(){
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://e/api/login")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let jsonpostParameters = LoginData(jsonrpc: "2.0", params: (PostLogin(email: nameTf.text!, password: passwordTf.text!, device_id: "2")))
        
    do {
        let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(jsonpostParameters)
        request.httpBody = jsonBody
    } catch {
        print("Error while encoding parameter: \(error)")
    }
        let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { [self] (data, response, error) in
            
            guard let data = data else {return}
            
        do{
            
            let jsonModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(Employees.self, from: data)

            print("new model \(jsonModel.result)")
            
                            
            DispatchQueue.main.sync{
                if jsonModel.error != nil{
                let controller = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Your email is not verified", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                controller.addAction(ok)
                controller.addAction(cancel)

                self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
                
                
            else{
                
                let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as? ProfileViewController
                vc?.userData = jsonModel
                vc?.tokenKey = jsonModel.result!.token

                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
                
            }
            }
            print("the error is \(error)")
        }catch{ print("Error while decoding: \(error.localizedDescription)") }
        }
        task.resume()
    
}
```

how to write all code in one function with different `urls` and different `parameters`  and handle the response from JSON, to call that function in all view controllers, pls do help with code

Answer (score 0):

Here check this protocol

```
protocol Networking {
func fetch(_ url: String, _ params:[String : Any], completion: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void)
}


extension Networking {
func fetch(_ url: String, _ params:[String : Any], completion: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) {
    
    //create the url with URL
    let url = URL(string: url)!
    //now create the URLRequest object using the url object
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST
    
    do {
        urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    // Set this in header if required
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
        
            if let error = error {
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                preconditionFailure("No error was received but we also don't have data...")
            }
            completion(data, nil)

    }.resume()
}
}
```

And use this as below example

```
class SampleViewController: UIViewController, Networking {
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let url = "https://e/api/login"
    let jsonpostParameters: [String: Any] = [:]
    
    self.fetch(url, jsonpostParameters) { (data: Data?, error: Error?) in
        guard let dt = data else { return }
// convert data to JSON
 print(dt)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i am new to this concept, may i know what is this `fetch<T: Decodable>`

Comment: It's generics. Let me edit code for you fro non-generics .

Comment: @iosSwift, check now.

Comment: @iosSwift you may want to use generics as Gour suggested.

Comment: if i add parameters like this `let jsonpostParameters = LoginData(jsonrpc: "2.0", params: (PostLogin(email: nameTf.text!, password: passwordTf.text!, device_id: "2")))`

Comment: error: `Cannot convert value of type 'LoginData' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'`

Comment: Parameter take argument  type [String : Any] not 'LoginData'.  Check this one https://www.advancedswift.com/http-requests-in-swift/